# Add a external loading/information screen for blender addon

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I am in the process of developing a Blender addon that involves certain operations requiring a significant amount of time to complete. When executing demanding processes from the addon Blender's main interface can appear to go white or unresponsive, even though it is actively processing tasks in the background, as evidenced by the console.

I am interested in incorporating an additional pop-up window that provides users with real-time information about the ongoing operations and which percentage it is from being completed. How can I achieve this functionality?